# AlarmManager not firing alarms if I kill app process

Tags: android, widget, android-widget, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I'm launching an alarm with this code:

```
private void startWidgetAlarm(Context context){
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ComboWidgetAlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60000, 60000, alarmIntent); //dispara cada 30 segundos desde el arranque
}
```

If I kill the app process, the alarm is not being fired any more. Why? is not supposed that if you create a repeating alarm it will repeat until the infinite?

Which alternatives do I have that will continue repeating jobs even with app process killed by the user or system? I have a widget which I must update even with the app killed.

Comment: What you can do is to re-register your alarms when the user starts your app again, or when the phone is rebooted.

Comment: Could you check by changing setInexactRepeating() with any exact one?

Comment: you can use Evernote's android job which works really out of the box.https://github.com/evernote/android-job

Comment: but will it work if the app is killed?